# HTML-outputting WYSIWYG editors for use in websites with longer text

Tags: gratis, web-apps, editor

I am looking to make a website for writing books. Rather obviously, the most crucial part of this is its editor. I plan for people to be able to upload `.docx`, `.scriv`, LaTeX, and Markdown files, but for others who may not be familiar with these or want to use a different way, I need a fully online editor.

Some of the things I have researched about so far, good though they are, aren't suitable for the long format that books require. Even if I only allowed to edit a chapter at a time, it would be rather preposterous to use something like [Froala](http://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). Does anyone know of a good one? I've also investiagated [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about), but it's immediately evident that it's more code-oriented. Perhaps it would be good for people looking to write in LaTeX online, but is not suitable for my purposes. If anyone requires a detailed list of requirements, please say so in the comments. As an aside, free would be absolutely wonderful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What formats must be supported? I know e.g. of *ownCloud* having a Markdown editor integrated into its core, and offering integration of OpenOffice/LibreOffice via addon. The latter might also work in your case, and there are IMHO several Markdown web-editors available as well.

Comment: @Izzy Not a markdown one, a WYSIWYG one. For people who want to use markdown (or LaTeX as I said in the question), I am already using Ace.

Comment: So maybe [LibreOffice as web service](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Using_LibreOffice_in_a_Web_Browser) could be fitting? Show-stopper might be `.docx`. My experiences using that format to exchange data with the MS world have not been that convincing (I'm author of several books and have to "exchange data" with publishers).

Comment: @Izzy Few problems: 

- It's server-side. Not a very huge thing, it's not a requirement for client-side however it is preferable
- The LibreOffice UI absolutely and totally sucks. We all know this.

(**EDIT**: Apparently bullet points don't work in comments.)